# Detect alarm in onReceive() method and match with Room Database

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-room

I have two alarm which fires at an interval of 3 min. What will I store in the Room database so that I can know which alarm is firing? I am using `TIME_ONE` and `TIME_TWO` to pass a value and detecting in the receiver end. But I think it is bad practice for large number of alarms. It would be better it I can match the id of the alarm that will fire with the stored id in the Room database. Or if I store store the requestcode in the db then how will I get the request code in the onReceive method. I have also tried `alarmIntent.putExtra(TIME_ONE, 2);` and `alarmIntent.putExtra(TIME_ONE, 1);` I am not sure if one name can hold two values and work fine. What will be the id of the alarm so that I can get the exact alarm in the `onReceive` method as it fires? If I pass the `requestcode` using `putExtra` should I use one tag (`TIME_ONE`) or multiple tags(`TIME_ONE`, `TIME_TWO`) to detect alarms? I don't want to use if else to check which one throwing 1 so that I can handle. How can I use intent of the onReceive method so that I can know directly which alarm is firing? **You can imagine the scenario as two alarms set time to alarm and detect for which alarm the onReceive method is called.**

```
private void setAlarm() {
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, MyAlarmReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent.putExtra(TIME_ONE, 1);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, alarmIntent, 0);
    manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    int interval = 1000 * 60 * 3; // 3 min
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 22);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);


    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);// repeat every two min interval

}
private void setSecAlarm() {
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, MyAlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent.putExtra(TIME_TWO, 1);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 2, alarmIntent, 0);
        manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        int interval = 1000 * 60 * 3; // 3 min
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 22);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 3);

        manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);// repeat every two min interval
    }
```

The `onReceive` method:

```
Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int hour = instance.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        int minute = instance.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int second = instance.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        int which_one = intent.getIntExtra(TIME_ONE,0);
        int which_two = intent.getIntExtra(TIME_TWO,0);

        if(which_one == 1 && which_two == 0){
            Log.d(MY_TAG, hour+":"+minute+":"+second+ "  First alarm called");
        }else if(which_one == 0 && which_two == 1){
            Log.d(MY_TAG, hour+":"+minute+":"+second+"  Second alarm called");
        }else{
            Log.d(MY_TAG, hour+":"+minute+":"+second+ "  none of them");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, hope you've solved this already of course .

I 'd just pass an id of the database row in the alarm intent.
The Insert Dao will return an Id, use it as the alarm identifier, and in onreceive you directly get the relevant row.